# Prevent duplicated objects affection each other C#

Tags: c#, class, oop

this might seem silly, so please excuse my naivety.

If I had an integer, say `int counter = 2;` then I could create integer `int anotherCounter = counter;` and if I were to print the value of `anotherCounter`, it would obviously return 2.

Now, if I then said `anotherCounter = 5;` then this would not change the value of our first value, `counter`. Likewise, if I changed the value of `counter` to `counter = 10;`, then that wouldn't affect `anotherCounter`.

However, I've created a class that I have used to instantate some objects, but if I do what I just described to my objects, they all seem to share the same values:

```
HSVImage initial = new HSVImage(1920, 1080);
HSVImage duplicate = initial;
```

For some reason, if I now change anything in `duplicate`, then it also affects `intial`. Can someone explain where I've gone wrong? I assume it's to do with how I set up my HSVImage Class?

Thank you.
Sam

Comment: In addition to answers below, if you want to achieve similar behavior of your HSVImage class as it's value type, consider change it from class into struct which is value type.

Answer (score 1):

That's because objects are passed and copied by **Reference** unlike primitives that are being passed by **Value**.

When you write

```
HSVImage initial = new HSVImage(1920, 1080);
HSVImage duplicate = initial;
```

you will copy the **Reference** to `initial` into `duplicate` which means that `initial` will now point at the same object as `duplicate`

on the other hand, when you write

```
int counter = 2;
int other = counter;
```

you will place the **Value** of `counter` inside `other`.

You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! I understand what you mean by this, but I still don't know how to fix my problem. How do I go about making my duplicate a value instead of a reference? In the documentation it says that I'd have had to put 'ref' in the parameters, but I haven't, so why does it think it's a reference?

Comment: You can use the **Copy constructor**

    `HSVImage initial = new HSVImage(1920, 1080);
    HSVImage duplicate = new HSVImage(initial);`
This will create a new object with the same attributes as the first one.

Comment: Ah right, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not part of your `HSVImage` class setup, it's how .Net framework handles **reference** type which is object of `HSVImage` class as oppose to **value** type which is your `counter` variable. Please read more about the topic at the following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx